# Using a Try and Catch function to skip unmatched cells

Tags: vba, excel

Someone helped me out with code for VBA in Excel.  My code is as follows:

```
Sub VidyaGames()

Dim LastRow As Variant, j As Integer

LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Address
j = 2

For i = 1 To Range("A1", LastRow).Rows.Count + 1 Step 10

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1) = Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Cells(i, 2)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Cells(i + 1, 2)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Range(Cells(i + 3, 1), Cells(i + 3, 1).End(xlToRight)))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Range(Cells(i + 4, 1), Cells(i + 4, 1).End(xlToRight)))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 5) = Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Cells(i + 5, 2)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 6) = Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Cells(i + 6, 2)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 7) = Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Cells(i + 7, 2)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 8) = Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Cells(i + 8, 2)

Try
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA ((Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(730, Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Range(Cells(i + 2, 1), Cells(i + 2, 1).End(xlToRight)), 0)))
Catch
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9) = 0


j = j + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

The code takes data from "Blocks" in one sheet and puts them into a readable/SPSS-like format in another sheet.  I added the Try and Catch code at the bottom, but it doesn't seem to be working.  If i run the line without the *Try* and *Catch* line, the code will terminate when it finds a row that does NOT contain the identifier ("730").  I looked up *try* and *catch*, thinking it was like Python's *try* and *except* but when I try to run it i get the message "Compile error: Sub or function not defined" and *Try* is highlighted.

Does *Try/Catch* work like Python's *Try/Except*?  If so, how do I get it to work here?

Comment: Oh...  Is there something else I can use to get the same effect?

Comment: Yes there is: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you.  I don't know how to mark a comment as a correct answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While VBA has no such thing as a Try/Catch block you could use standard Error Handling for this such as

```
Sub VidyaGames()

    For i = 1 To Range("A1", LastRow).Rows.Count + 1 Step 10
        ....
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9) = TryCatchWorkAround(i)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function TryCatchWorkAround(i AS Integer) AS Integer
On Error GoTo Handler
     TryCatchWorkAround = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA ((Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(730, Worksheets("PlayerInfoAll").Range(Cells(i + 2, 1), Cells(i + 2, 1).End(xlToRight)), 0))) 

Exit_TryCatchWorkAround:
    Exit Function
Handler:
    TryCatchWorkAround = 0
    Resume Exit_TryCatchWorkAround
End Function
```

This will perform the same function just using VBA Standard Error Handling.

Comment: Why the `GoTo Exit_TryCatchWorkAround`? Also, it should be `End Function` instead of `Exit Function`on the last line

Comment: @z̫͋ I always specify a `Goto Exit_XXX` in case there is additional clean up that needs to be done prior to leaving the `Function` or `Sub`. In this case it is not needed but implementing in this way allows for the same functionality as `finally` does in `java` or `ensure` does in `ruby`. It makes for DRYer code in the case where you need to release objects or perform other functionality after the fact regardless of errors. The `Exit Function` at the end was a simple typo and has been fixed thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

VBA does not offer try/catch blocks. You could try modifying error handling by using `On Error Goto xxx` where `xxx` is a label where your error handling code resides. Look up `On Error Goto ...` on the internet for more information.